# where do i place NaN code?

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer

Here is a new question. I want to make my Nan say "this is not a number" if nothing or text is entered. I know the physical code but I dont know where to put it or if I must make a function. Where ever I put it it either loops and say what ever was inputted first and then then "this is not a number" or "this is not a number" then NaN or it doesn't work at all.

```
javacript:
window.onload = function (){

var myDiv = document.getElementById("wrapper");
wrapper.setAttribute("align","center");
var startButton = document.getElementById("start");
var pauseButton = document.getElementById("pause");
var secondsBlock = document.getElementById("seconds");
var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
var newTime = document.createElement("h1");

    newTime.innerHTML = secondsBlock.value;
    timer.appendChild(newTime);

    //setTimeout(function countdown () {
     var numbers = (newTime.innerHTML);
     newTime.innerHTML = numbers;

var newNumber;

function countdown(count){

    newNumber =secondsBlock.value;
    var numbers = (newNumber);
    newTime.innerHTML = numbers;

    stopper = setInterval(reduceAndShow, 1000);

    if (numbers <10){
        newTime.style.color = "red";
        newTime.innerHTML = "0" + numbers;
    };   

};

function reduceAndShow(){
    newNumber--;
    var numbers = (newNumber);
    newTime.innerHTML = numbers;

    stopCountdown();

    if (newNumber <10){
        newTime.style.color = "red";
        newTime.innerHTML= "0" + newNumber;
    };  


};

function stopCountdown(){
    if(newNumber <= 0){
    clearInterval(stopper);
    };
};

startButton.onclick = function(){
    countdown();
};  

function pauseBut(){
    clearInterval(stopper);
};

pauseButton.onclick =function(){
    pauseBut()
    };

html:
<div id="wrapper">
Seconds: <input type="text" name= "seconds" id="seconds"> <input type="button"    
value="Start" id="start"> <input type="button" value="Pause" id="pause">

<div id="extraText"></div>

 <div id="timer"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code, or even better, a demo.

Comment: how do you add a demo its say my code is too long to add

Comment: I've changed my answer to reflect the code you've posted. I hope it's what you were after. Make sure you see if it works by clicking at this url: http://jsfiddle.net/QxdUy/

Answer (score 2):

You should get your example running in JSFiddle.net so people can see the whole thing, and investigate for you why it isn't working.

[Here's one I made for you.](http://jsfiddle.net/QxdUy/)

I've changed your code to the below. The main difference is I split it into two functions. One which checks that the input is a valid number, and the other does the counting down / displaying. One other little thing I changed was the way you declared the countdown function, you sort of declared it twice, I've changed it so it's only declared once:

```
window.onload = function(){

    var myDiv = document.getElementById("wrapper");
    var startButton = document.getElementById("start");
    va r pauseButton = document.getElementById("pause");
    var secondsBlock = document.getElementById("seconds");
    var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
    var newTime = document.createElement("h1");


    function countdown(count) {
        newTime.innerHTML = count;
        if (count < 10) {
            newTime.style.color = "red";
        };
        timer.appendChild(newTime);
        if (count > 0) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                countdown(count - 1);
            }, 1000);
        }
    }


    function testInput() {
        var count = seconds.value;
        if (count == "" || isNaN(count)) {
            newTime.innerHTML = "This is not a number";
            timer.appendChild(newTime);
        } else if (count > 100) {
            newTime.innerHTML = "Number must be between 0 and 99"
            timer.appendChild(newTime);
        } else {
            countdown(count);
        }

    }

    startButton.onclick = testInput;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a very simple case of

```
if (typeof(seconds.value) == "number") { newTime.innerHTML = seconds.value; }
else { newTime.innerHTML = "This is not a number"; }
timer.appendChild(newTime);
```

Comment: this (from my small javascript knowledge) still shows what i've typed into the box first before it shows the This is not a number